# Why doesn't Animation Nodes' '3D Viewer' node display anything in the viewport when connected to a 'Distribute Matrices' node?

Tags: animation-nodes

In Blender 2.81.16, AN 2.1.5 connecting a 3D Viewer to the Distribute Matrices does nothing - you would expect there to be 16 here...
[image]

In the following animation from the Animation Nodes docs it looks like a plain axes is being manipulated. However, there doesn't seem to be anything connecting a plain axes to the nodes. 
[image]

Am I missing something that is assumed about the setups shown in the Animation Nodes documentation?

For comments...the setup!
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make your title specific to the question you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ray, Could you suggest what would be an appropriate way to make this post title more specific. It's a general question because its about if there are assumptions across all of AN docs...

Comment: did you turn on "auto execution" on "always"?

Comment: You can enable the 3D Viewer node by pressing the small dot button (just next to the Width option).

Comment: Had enabled the 3D Viewer. Still a no go. I built the exact node setup (Distribute Matrix > 3D Viewer) and don't get anything, let alone what is shown in the docs.